# CustomClass Reference in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I am new to `Objective C` and `Swift`. I have created a SampleTest project in Swift.. While creating a `ViewController.xib` we need to give the `reference class` in identity inspector which is contain in right side pane in xcode.

[image]

ViewController denotes the `ViewController.swift` module and Here what it denotes **_TtC10SampleTest14ViewController** in class field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**_TtC10SampleTest14ViewController** is the **mangled** name of your `ViewController`, swift using `Name Mangling` .
1. Read more about name mangling in [this article](http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/)
2.
Check the related [answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283804/swift-reverse-engineeringswift-function-name-rule/24284328#24284328)

Comment: its very useful article by Evan Swick.. thanks for share it :)